# Why does my JLabel subclass not properly execute setIcon(..)?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I created a class called RichJLabel that will add a drop shadow to my JLabels. I noticed that setting an icon no longer works, like it did when using JLabel. Anyone know why this may be the case? I think it is to do with preferred size?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;

public class RichJLabel extends JLabel {

    private int tracking;
    private int left_x, left_y, right_x, right_y;
    private Color left_color, right_color;

    public RichJLabel(String text, int tracking) {
        super(text);
        this.tracking = tracking;
    }

    public void setLeftShadow(int x, int y, Color color) {
        left_x = x;
        left_y = y;
        left_color = color;
    }

    public void setRightShadow(int x, int y, Color color) {
        right_x = x;
        right_y = y;
        right_color = color;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        String text = getText();
        FontMetrics fm = this.getFontMetrics(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));

        int w = fm.stringWidth(text);
        w += (text.length()-1)*tracking;
        w += left_x + right_x;

        int h = fm.getHeight();
        h += left_y + right_y;

        return new Dimension(w,h);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        char[] chars = getText().toCharArray();

        FontMetrics fm = this.getFontMetrics(getFont());
        int h = fm.getAscent();
        LineMetrics lm = fm.getLineMetrics(getText(),g);
        g.setFont(getFont());

        int x = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
            char ch = chars[i];
            int w = fm.charWidth(ch) + tracking;

            g.setColor(left_color);
            g.drawString(""+chars[i],x-left_x,h-left_y);

            g.setColor(right_color);
            g.drawString(""+chars[i],x+right_x,h+right_y);

            g.setColor(getForeground());
            g.drawString(""+chars[i],x,h);

            x+=w;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `I noticed that setting an icon no longer works, like it did when using JLabel.` - The paintComponent() method is responsible for doing all the JLabel painting. That is Icon and text. You overrode the paintComponent() method to paint the label. You only paint the text. If you want the Icon then you are also responsible for painting the Icon.

Comment: Oh darn, do you know how I could that?

Comment: You can paint the Icon yourself by using the Icon.paintIcon(...) method. Of course you will need to do all the calculations to determine the offsets of where to paint the Icon and the text. So basically you need to duplicate all the painting code of JLabel.

Comment: You'll almost certainly want to make use of [SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#layoutCompoundLabel-javax.swing.JComponent-java.awt.FontMetrics-java.lang.String-javax.swing.Icon-int-int-int-int-java.awt.Rectangle-java.awt.Rectangle-java.awt.Rectangle-int-).  Remember to set all three Rectangle arguments to 0,0,labelWidth,labelHeight before calling it.

Comment: You should also be calling the `Override` annotation on all inherited methods and be calling `paintComponent`'s super method